# Filter views table by terms present in another display

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view with two displays. The first shows nodes that have field "`term_field`" among others. This first display has an exposed filter of other field.

In my second display, I have a table of nodes of a different content type that also has the same "`term_field`" (the taxonomy is shared). This second display is attached to the first one.

What I need is that, when I filter the first display, the second one is also filtered by only the terms that are present in the first one.

I hope the requirement is clear. Any one knows how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make the displays into View blocks, then show them on the same page so that they share the contextual filter in the URL?

Comment: I wanted to show the data as a table because there are a few fields and some with long strings. If a block is a solution, I can put them in the content yes.

Comment: In the attached display ATTACHMENT SETTINGS there is an option for Inherit Exposed Filters.. Set it to yes. It assumes that you have added the same exposed filter to this attachment.